# nodejs async await inside iterator for loop in mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to test the usage of an asynchronous generator using the async and await paradigm.

I have a generator function yielding results from a stream:

```js
async function* getChunkOfData(filepath) {
  try {
    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    const parser = parse();
    await pipelineAsync(inputStream, parser);
    for await (const line of parser) {
      yield line;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error while reading csv file: " + err.message);
  }
}
```

I'm getting line by line in my test and using it as input for an asynchronous function. From the test, I'm getting a timeout error and only the first iteration of the for loop is executed. Here my test code:

```js
describe("My test suite", function () {
  it("My test", async function () {
    try {
      const iterator = getChunkOfData("example.csv");
      for await (const row of iterator) {
        await asyncCall(row);
        // some expect logic using chai
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(await err);
      assert.throw(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Please note, that I've already tried to increase the test timeout, without any better results also because the `asyncCall` is executed quite fastly.

Comment: Reading from the file system is going to make your test slow and hard to maintain. You probably want to mock the file system instead, which will make the test faster, more predictable and reliable. 

Refactor your function to take `fs` as input, and on the test pass a mocked version of `fs` instead of the real one.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like a reasonable workaround. I'm wondering if this way to use the generator and the `asyncCall` in the real code is fine or if I'm leaving behind some errors...

Comment: Ok I found the error. It was related to `asyncCall` function. I was not ending it properly. My bad